# How to create a DevExtreme Application Template with CSS instead of SCSS files?

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I want to create an Application Template using DevExtreme, but it generates the code with SCSS files below. I would like to create it with CSS files instead.

```
npx devextreme-cli new angular-app app-name
```